# Flutter BottomAppBar demo has misaligned icon button shape on iPhone 14

Tags: flutter, material-design

When I run the BottomAppBar [demo](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomAppBar-class.html) on ios using a iPhone 14 pro max, the button icon background color is misaligned:

[image]

When I run the same code in dartpad or on other devices without a bottom device curve (Linux Desktop for example), I do not see this behavior:

[image]

I assume what is happening is the SafeArea that is found in the BottomAppBar widget is pushing that upward? Is there a way to workaround this behavior without increasing the visible height of the BottomAppBar?

I am on the latest stable flutter:

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.4.1 xxxxxxx darwin-x64,
locale en-US)

I tried increasing the BottomAppBar height to 100 in order to move that icon out of the SafeArea:

```
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      height: isVisible ? 100.0 : 0,
```

This does work, but it makes the BottomAppBar too large.